# How can I write in python a for loop with function that changes based on i?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the following variables:

```
info0=["info01","info02","info03","info04",]
info1=["info11","info12","info13","info14",]
info2=["info21","info22","info23","info24",]
info3=["info31","info32","info33","info34",]
info4=["info41","info42","info43","info44",]
info5=["info51","info52","info53","info54",]
```

and I have the following function that prints the elements of a list:

```
def printelements(list_of_i):
    for element in list_of_i:
        print(element)
```

so I want to create a loop to go thought all the lists above and print all the elements:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    printelements(info(i)) <-- so the function should change based on the i, in order to print all the lists
```

How can I do the above? I know alternative ways to print the lists, but I want to focus on the variable to change based on the `i`.

Comment: To sum it up: You think you need to do it like this, but you actually don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters I would recommend just having a list of info.

```py
for info in [info0, info1, info2, info3, info4]:
    printelements(info)
```

You might also be able to do something with the `eval()` command, but I wouldn't recommend it.

```py
for i in range(5):
    printelements(eval("info{}".format(i)))
```

However, using this would be such bad practice that I'm not even sure if it will work. It is such bad practice to use `eval()` in this way that I have never tried code like this. I'm just bringing it up for the sake of argument.

Answer (score 0):

no need for a function here since you probably wont reuse it and it doesnt really minimize code

```
[[print(i) for i in lst] for lst in [info0,info1,info2,info3,info4,info5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to figure out how to compute variable names on the fly, but instead to add another layer of list. A list of lists.

Rule of thumb: Any time you have variable names with numbers attached you should probably be using a list.

```
info = [
    ["info01","info02","info03","info04",],
    ["info11","info12","info13","info14",],
    ["info21","info22","info23","info24",],
    ["info31","info32","info33","info34",],
    ["info41","info42","info43","info44",],
    ["info51","info52","info53","info54",],
]

for i in range(0,5):
    printelements(info[i])
```

You can also get rid of `i` and loop over the sublists directly:

```
for sublist in info:
    printelements(sublist)
```